# Impossible to capture 503 even with AngularJS' http interceptor

Tags: angularjs, http, interceptor, restangular

I'm wondering why I cannot capture the status 503 when I encounter the error. HTTP interceptor captures the error with a status of 0. Is it even possible? If so, can you provide a code please?

Comment: what's the status code of the API call in your Network panel?

Comment: BTW, what Angular version you are using?

Comment: Where are my comments earlier? I mentioned earlier that I fixed it already. I mentioned that the culprit happens only in development environment since the status code captured is 0. When I deployed it to our integration which has an FQDN, it was able to capture 503.

Comment: Ah, I know now why it's gone. The other person who commented on this post deleted his reply. My comment was in his response. When he deleted it, mine got deleted since it was part of it.

Comment: Good to know it works now. I just find earlier version of Angular actually has this [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1423#issuecomment-10271542).

Comment: Does it still not work locally? If so, it would be difficult to develop/debug.

Comment: http interceptor does actually capture the error even when you're in your development environment(localhost:9000) but it doesn't know what http error it is. The status code is 0 and other properties returned are undefined or blank.