# angularjs Interceptor:why is it not receiving the proper status code and message in $http interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-503

I am making a simple get request using `$http` .and it fails with `503-service unavailable` error which is clearly shown in the network tab .But the `rejection` object in the `responseError` interceptor object shows `status: 0`.

Here is my Interceptor

```
angular.module("app", []).config(function($httpProvider){
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
  return {
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
       console.log(rejection);
    }
  }
})
});
```

I am expecting status code `503` in the interceptor but i am getting `0`.Please help me to understand and resolve the issue.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/divm/3unu5f7c/2/) is a fiddle illustrating the issue.

The request is a cross domain request.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257824/impossible-to-capture-503-even-with-angularjs-http-interceptor ? Looks like it has something to do with the environment in which you run your code.

Comment: @MattHerbstritt that is the same problem i am dealing with except the fiddle doesn't work irrespective of the environment .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service you are using does return any data.  Angular $http expects some data to be returned, and in this case "GetStatusCode" just stops and does not return anything.

Also, fyi - your fiddle does not respect angular's method of binding to a controller, which expects a string for the controller name.

See http://plnkr.co/edit/x46D5FIsgaKsaSocYjpz?p=preview for proper markup.. where we name the controller as a string, for ex:

```
angular.module("plunker", [])

    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function () {
            return {
                'responseError': function (rejection) {
                    console.log('rejection = ', rejection);
                },
                'response': function (response) {
                    console.log('response = ', response);
                }
            }
        })
    })

    .controller('Controller', function Controller($scope, $http) {
        $scope.getCode = function () {
            var req = 'http://www.reddit.com/r/catpictures.json?limit=50&jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';
            return $http.jsonp(req);
        };
        $scope.get = function () {
            return $scope.getCode()
        };
    })
;
```